# Context broker is ignoring value, fiware orion and iotagent

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

orion version : 2.3.0
iotagent-ul version : 1.12.0

I am using fiware and iotagent over mqtt. I want to send commands to some devices with different values. I have followed https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT and read some documentation.
After provisionning a service group (with apikey: 123456) and an actuator, I can send commands with values by following the iota URL :

```
curl -iX POST \                       
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "dev001",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:001",
      "entity_type": "Device",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "MQTT",
      "commands": [
        {"name": "date","type": "command", "value": {"hour": 9, "minute": 31, "second": 0}}
       ]
    }
  ]
}
'
```

iota publish a mqtt message to : /123456/dev001/cmd with payload `dev001@date|hour=9|minute=31|second=0`

But when using the context broker, the value is ignored :

```
curl -iX PATCH \                                 
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Device:001/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "date": {            
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : {"hour": 9, "minute": 31, "second": 0}     
  }                                                                            
}'
```

Here, iota publish a mqtt message to : /123456/dev001/cmd with payload `dev001@date|`

Why is it ignored ? Am I doing somthing wrong ?

sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution... adding the type in the url make the context take account of the value... weird.

The final url must be :

```
curl -iX PATCH \                                 
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Device:001/attrs?type=Device' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "date": {            
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : {"hour": 9, "minute": 31, "second": 0}     
  }                                                                            
}'
```

**EDIT:**

knowing the solution, I have tried to understand the problem and found this issue : https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3647

> According to CPrs and request forwarding documentation
>
> > On forwarding, any type of entity in the NGSIv2 update/query matches
> >     registrations without entity type. However, the opposite doesn't work,
> >     so if you have registrations with types, then you must use ?type in
> >     NGSIv2 update/query in order to obtain a match. Otherwise you may
> >     encounter problems, like the one described in this post at
> >     StackOverflow.

**EDIT 2:**

This is a duplicate of : [Orion CB doesn't update lazy attributes on IoT Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163972/orion-cb-doesnt-update-lazy-attributes-on-iot-agent)